# SwiftUI: Updating Model with a timer and reflecting it in UI

Tags: swiftui

I created a little demo app to demonstrate my problem:
I have a model that has an Int which gets incremented every second. A ViewModel is observed by the view and converts this Int to a String which should be displayed.
The problem is that I see the incrementation in the console but the UI is not getting updated. Where is the problem? I used the same approach in other apps. Is the timer the problem?

I'm aware that the naming is not good, it is just for simplicity here. Heartbeatemitter is a separate class because the Timer needs it and I will use in different views inside my app where I pass around the same instance. Why is my Viewmodel not recognising the change of the model?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.number)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published private var model: Model
    
    init() {
        model = Model(emitter: HeartbeatEmitter())
        model.heartbeatEmitter.delegate = model
    }
    
    var number: String {
        "\(model.number)"
    }
}

protocol Heartbeat {
    mutating func beat()
}

struct Model: Heartbeat {
    
    var heartbeatEmitter: HeartbeatEmitter
    var number: Int = 0
    
    init(emitter: HeartbeatEmitter){
        self.heartbeatEmitter = emitter
    }
    
    mutating func beat() {
        number += 1
        print(number)
    }
}

class HeartbeatEmitter {
    
    private var timer: Timer!
    var delegate: Heartbeat?
    
    init() {
        setupTimer()
    }
    
    func setupTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(notifyDelegate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
    }
    
    @objc
    func notifyDelegate() {
        delegate?.beat()
    }
}
```

Comment: `HeartbeatEmitter` changes aren't being observed, stick to using `struct` or `class` combining adds complications. if you stick to `class` use it in conjunction with `ObservableObject` and observe at all levels. Look into `TimelineView` it might help.

Comment: But the model is mutating. The number changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on a `mutating` member of the `struct` to project the changes to the `@Published` wrapper. I'd use something that explicitly gets/sets the model.

This, for example, works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.number)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject, HeartbeatModifier {
    
    @Published private var model = Model()
    var emitter = HeartbeatEmitter()
    
    init() {
        emitter.delegate = self
    }
    
    func beat() {
        model.number += 1
    }
    
    var number: String {
        "\(model.number)"
    }
}

protocol HeartbeatModifier {
    func beat()
}

protocol Heartbeat {
    var number : Int { get set }
}

struct Model: Heartbeat {
    var number: Int = 0
}

class HeartbeatEmitter {
    
    private var timer: Timer!
    var delegate: HeartbeatModifier?
    
    init() {
        setupTimer()
    }
    
    func setupTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(notifyDelegate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
    }
    
    @objc
    func notifyDelegate() {
        delegate?.beat()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Model` is a `struct`, which makes it a value type. That means that when you pass a `Model` to a function, you're actually making a copy of it and passing that copy to the function.

In particular, this line makes a copy of `model`:

> ```
>        model.heartbeatEmitter.delegate = model
> ```

The “function call” is the call to the setter of `delegate`. So the `delegate` property of the `HeartbeatEmitter` stores its own copy of `Model`, which is completely independent of the copy stored in the `model` property of the `ViewModel`. The `Model` stored in the `HeartbeatEmitter`'s `delegate` is being modified, but the `Model` stored in the `ViewModel`'s `model` property is not being modified.

I recommend you move the responsibility for side effects (like events based on the passage of time) out of your model object and into a control object: in this case, your `ViewModel`.

Furthermore, your code will be simpler if you use the Combine framework's `Timer.Publisher` to emit your time-based events, instead of hand-rolling your own `Heartbeat` and `HeartbeatEmitter` types.

Finally, this line also has a problem:

> ```
>     @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
> ```

The problem here is that you are not being honest with SwiftUI about the lifetime of `viewModel` and so it may be replaced with a new instance of `ViewModel` when you don't expect. You should be using `@StateObject` here. Read [this article by Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject) for more details.

Thus:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.number)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published private var model: Model
    private var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []

    init() {
        model = Model()
        Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink { [weak self] _ in self?.model.beat() }
            .store(in: &tickets)
    }

    var number: String {
        "\(model.number)"
    }
}

struct Model {
    var number: Int = 0

    mutating func beat() {
        number += 1
        print(number)
    }
}
```